# View data structures of .pkl file

Tags: python

I try to view the data structures of ExtremeNet_250000.pkl( size about 780M) by the code:

```
import pickle
pth=open(r'E:/ExtremeNet_250000.pkl','rb')
pkl=pickle.load(pth)
print(pkl)
```

but it return the int just like

```
RESTART: C:/Users/cwc888888/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/111.py =
119547037146038801333356
```

could you give me some suggestion?

Comment: Without more context, I would check what `type(pkl)` returns.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve after loading the pickle? Just look at the data, convert it into some other type etc? Without more context, the approach mentioned by @sal would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case:

Based on your file name, I'm guessing you're playing around with [the `ExtremeNet` demo project](https://github.com/xingyizhou/ExtremeNet/blob/master/demo.py). Tracing through the code and dependencies, it looks like that cache file is the result of a `torch.save` call from the `PyTorch` package. Simplest solution for this case is probably just to install `PyTorch`, and [use `torch.load` to load it](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.load).

---

General solution:

It's possible to save multiple pickled objects in a file in an unstructured manner. That is, rather than saving a `list` as a `list` with a single:

```
 with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
     pickle.dump(mylist, f)
```

the creator could dump the individual values one by one with:

```
 with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
     for x in mylist:
         pickle.dump(x, f)
     # Or equivalently and usually slightly faster creating a single reusable Pickler:
     pickler = pickle.Pickler(f)
     for x in mylist:
         pickler.dump(x)
```

removing the `list` structure from the output.

If you've got such a file, you have to read the values out in a similar way. The simplest approach is to make a generator function that will yield successive values when iterated, e.g.:

```
def iterunpickle(f):
    unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(f)
    try:
        while True:
            yield unpickler.load()
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

allowing you to iterate the contents of your file with:

```
with open(r'E:/ExtremeNet_250000.pkl','rb') as pth:
    for item in iterunpickle(pth):
        print(item)
```

or load the whole thing into a `list` (if sufficient memory available) with:

```
with open(r'E:/ExtremeNet_250000.pkl','rb') as pth:
    items = list(iterunpickle(pth))
```

For a file that large, I'd recommend iterating live to preserve memory rather than converting to a `list` up front; if it's nothing but largish integers in the range of that first value, the memory cost to load the entire thing into a list would be roughly three times the disk size, depending on pickle protocol, whether your interpreter is 32 or 64 bit, etc. Regardless, you'd been looking a multiple GB of RAM for the data alone, before you did anything with it.